# Access VBA: Referring to a loop's counter within the loop

Tags: vba, loops, ms-access, scope

Is it possible to access the counter of a loop within the actual loop itself? The code below results in an Enter Parameter Value, as if something is wrong with the scope of the `For` loop.

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 To 100
        DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Table1 (Field1) VALUES (i);"
    Next i
End Sub
```

This behaviour is strange because an `If` statement is clearly able to access the counter of the `For` loop that it is contained of:

```
Sub test()
    For i = 1 to 100
        If i = 1 Then
            DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO Table1 (Field1) VALUES ('This works');"
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you simply write `i` inside the query string:

```
"INSERT INTO Table1 (Field1) VALUES (i);"
```

it refers to the column `i` (which probably doesn't exist). You need to build the string using the value of the variable `i`:

```
"INSERT INTO Table1 (Field1) VALUES (" & CStr(i) & ");"
```